Why didn't inflation happen right after creation and it had to wait $10^{-36}$ seconds to occur?
What caused this minimum delay in the universe faster than light expansion?

Related question/answer on Astronomy.SE

How is this unclear? If you know anything about cosmology you will know that inflation had to start some short but non-zero interval after time zero. If you don't know anything about cosmology you shouldn't be voting to close.

As I understand it, in these typical chronologies of inflation starting at 0, the extremely short duration of inflation refers to the 60 $e$-folds we need to see the structures in the observable universe. In principle, inflation could have lasted much longer, and usually HOW inflation started can be different from model to model, i.e. boils down to motivating certain initial conditions.

One idea - although I think this is some way being a consensus - is that the energy density of the early universe had to first fall below the grand unification energy, allowing the strong force to separate from the other fundamental forces. This phase transition from the grand unification epoch to the electroweak epoch in turn triggered inflation.

So if this is correct, could we say that the fundamental forces were holding dark energy together more or less from the second 0 to the 10^-36 second?

@Mr.Spock Dark energy is part of the Lambda-CDM cosmological model, which did not apply until well after the inflationary epoch. Don't confuse cosmic inflation (the very short inflationary epoch in the early universe) with the much slower  expansion of the current universe that is driven by dark energy.

Most of the inflationary models I have seen are single field inflation models with some non-trivial potential allowing for a phase where the field is stuck due to friction, leading to a high amount of negative pressure and high constant energy density, i.e. inflation. In these models, the inflationary field decays into Standard Models fields only after inflation... I don't see how in these models the "start" of inflation is related to GUT scale i.e.. There are also low scale inflation models where the universe NEVER reached GUT scale, if I am correctly informed. Could you elaborate a little?
